# Embeding style into the header via the function.php

Tags: hooks

I'm trying to add the following hook into my functions.php file. The CSS style shows up when I view the source code but it also show the php code for the random background image generator. How can I get the php in that line to work within the hook?

Thanks

```
add_action('wp_head','hook_css');
function hook_css()
{
    $output="
        <style>
            body {
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                background: url('../images/backgrounds/bg<?php echo rand(1,4)?>.jpg') no-repeat top center;
            }
    </style>";
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: I know but I'm not sure how else to add the background image generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not escaping your PHP correctly. In this part `$output="... <?php`
You could instead do it like this:

```
add_action('wp_head','hook_css');
function hook_css()
{
?> <!-- Closing the PHP here -->
    <style>
        body {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background: url('../images/backgrounds/bg<?php echo rand(1,4); ?>.jpg') no-repeat top center;
        }
    </style>
<?php //Opening the PHP tag again
}
```

Or if you prefer to have it the way you do with the `$output` variable - Make sure to escape correctly around your rand() function. Like this: `...backgrounds/bg". rand(1,4) .".jpg`

Comment: Cool thanks that works, though should I add something like `get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ` in the image line as a way to hide the full path to the image and if so whats the best way to do that?

Comment: You could do that with ``<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/...``

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to use the full URL to the background image. Otherwise the image might not appear on child pages or posts.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head','hook_css');
function hook_css()
{
    $output="
        <style>
            body {
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                background: url('" . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/images/bg" . rand(1,4) . ".jpg') no-repeat top center;
            }
    </style>";
    echo $output;
}
```